# XPath: select tag with empty value

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

How I can find in XPath 1.0 all rows with empty `col name="POW"`?

```
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW"/>
<col name="GMI"/>
<col name="RODZ"/>
<col name="NAZWA">DOLNOŚLĄSKIE</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">województwo</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2011-01-01</col>
</row>
```

I tried many solutions. Few times in Firefox extension XPath Checker selection was ok, but `lxml.xpath()` says that expression is invalid or just returns no rows.

My Python code:

```
from lxml import html
f = open('TERC.xml', 'r')
page = html.fromstring(f.read())
for r in page.xpath("//row[col[@name = 'POW' and not(text())]]"):
    print r.text_content()
    print "-------------------------"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How I can find in XPath 1.0 all rows with empty `col name="POW"`?

There are many possible definitions of "empty" and for each one of them there is a different XPath expression selecting "empty" elements.

A reasonable definition for an empty element is: an element that has no children elements and no text-node children, or an element that has a single text-node child, whose string value contains only whitespace characters.

**This XPath expression**:

```
//row[col[@name = 'POW']
                    [not(*)]
                       [not(normalize-space())]
      ]
```

selects all `row` elements in the XML document, that have a `col` child, that has an attribute `name` with string value `"POW"` and that has no children - elements and whose string value consists either entirely of whitespace characters, or is the empty string.

**In case by "empty" you understand "having no children at all"**, which means no children elements and no children PI nodes and no children comment nodes, then use:

```
//row[col[@name = 'POW']
                    [not(node())]
      ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//row[col[@name='POW' and not(normalize-space())]]
```

To ensure that the POW column also doesn't have any child elements(even if they don't contain any text), then add an additional predicate filter:

```
//row[col[@name='POW' and not(normalize-space()) and not(*)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
//row[col[@name = 'POW' and not(text())]]
```

Comment: There is unnecessary `)]` at end of expression... And it selects all rows in my code (in XPath Checker everything is ok). I updated my question...