# How to select all empty elements with XPath

Tags: xpath

Assume the following markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <strong>  </strong>
      <strong>
      </strong>
      <strong><em>Bar</em>  </strong>
      <strong><em>  </em>  </strong>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the following elements with a XPath query?

```
<strong>  </strong>
<strong>
</strong>
<strong><em>  </em>  </strong>
```

I've thought it would something like `//*[normalize-space(text()) = '' and not(node())]` for the first both cases but it's not. And I have no clue how to catch the third case.

**To be more precisely: I'm searching for all nodes which contain only white space, new lines and child nodes with the same.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688185/xpath-select-tag-with-empty-value

Please check the above post.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following XPath query catches them all:

```
//*[not(normalize-space())]
```

But not:

```
<strong><em>Bar</em>  </strong>
```

Comment: It will also catch `<em>  </em>`, which wasn't on the expected results list.

Comment: @MichaelKay It already catches its parent which is on the list, so I wouldn't care very much in this case ... but I could complete the list in my question if you wan't.