# Clean xml ==> Remove line if any empty tags

Tags: python, regex, xml

I would like to clean up my xml so that not only is it valid XML, but it is formatted in a very human readable way. For example:

```
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
</Items>
```

I would like to remove any lines with an empty tag, leaving:

```
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
</Items>
```

I tried doing this using a regex, but haven't been having much luck in terms of leaving it in a readable format:

```
txt = etree.tostring(self.xml_node, pretty_print=True)
txt = re.sub(r'<[a-zA-Z]+/>\n', '', txt)
```

What would be the best way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Why don't you remove empty nodes while it's still XML, rather than trying to do it when it's a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty tag"? Do you mean a standalone tag, even if its got attributes?

Comment: With the regex route this probably works `(?s)<[\w:]+(?:\s+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+)?/>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an *XML parser*.

The idea is to [find all empty nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688185/xpath-select-tag-with-empty-value) with `//*[not(node())]` XPath expression and [remove them from the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml). Example, using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree


data = """
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
</Items>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(data)
for element in root.xpath(".//*[not(node())]"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution can be considered for nth level depth for the XML data.

```
from lxml import etree

def recursively_empty(xml_element):
   if xml_element.text:
       return False
   return all((recursively_empty(xe) for xe in xml_element.iterchildren()))

data = """
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
</Items>
"""

xml_root = etree.iterwalk(data)

for action, xml_element in xml_root:
    parent = xml_element.getparent()
    if recursively_empty(xml_element):
        parent.remove(xml_element)
```

Please note: reason behind using recursive method is to address multi-level depth of XML data.

Solution should work for variety of depth

```
data1 = """
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition/>
</Items>
"""

data2 = """
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition>
        <cond1>Somedata</cond1>
    </Condition>
</Items>
"""

data3 = """
<Items>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Cost>9.99</Cost>
    <Condition>
        </cond1>
    </Condition>
</Items>
"""
```