# How to remove a specific tag that could be empty in an xml file

Tags: xml, python-3.x, tags, lxml, is-empty

I am trying to remove a specific tag from an xml file but only if it is empty.

file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
  <child>
    <value1>Foo<value1/>
    <value2>Bar<value2/>
    <value3>Hello World<value3/>
    <value3/>
    <value3/>
    <value3/>
  <child/>
<parent/>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
  <child>
    <value1>Foo<value1/>
    <value2>Bar<value2/>
    <value3>Hello World<value3/>
  <child/>
<parent/>
```

I am having problems reading a file and parsing it with `lxml` so I am open to any other python3 methods/modules.
ideally would like the code todo something like the following:

```
def remove_empty_tag(tag=tagname, file=data):
   ...

data = open("file.xml").read()
new_xml = remove_empty_tag(tag="value3", data)
print(new_xml)
```

but open for any help really or even direction.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652470/clean-xml-remove-line-if-any-empty-tags

Comment: Marco, That's definitely a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean xml ==> Remove line if any empty tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652470/clean-xml-remove-line-if-any-empty-tags)

Comment: I've looked at both and they weren't helpful because nothing explains how to read the xml file or why it complains about `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` when parsing it or how to write to a new file. They also don't specify how to remove only one specific tag name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `open()` the file for reading or writing; use lxml's [`parse()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) to parse the file and [`write()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) to write the new one.

You should also be able to use the `self::` xpath axis instead of a python `if` to check the tag name.

Example...

**XML Input** (old.xml)

```xml
<parent>
  <child>
    <value1>Foo</value1>
    <value2>Bar</value2>
    <value3>Hello World</value3>
    <value3/>
    <value3/>
    <value3/>
  </child>
</parent>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree


def remove_empty_tag(tag, original_file, new_file):
    root = etree.parse(original_file)
    for element in root.xpath(f".//*[self::{tag} and not(node())]"):
        element.getparent().remove(element)

    # Serialize "root" and create a new tree using an XMLParser to clean up
    # formatting caused by removing elements.
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    tree = etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(root), parser=parser)
    # Write to new file.
    etree.ElementTree(tree).write(new_file, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")


remove_empty_tag("value3", "old.xml", "new.xml")
```

**XML Output** (new.xml)

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
  <child>
    <value1>Foo</value1>
    <value2>Bar</value2>
    <value3>Hello World</value3>
  </child>
</parent>
```

---

**Note:** The serializing and creating a new tree is not strictly necessary. You could just do this instead:

```py
root.write(new_file, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

but the formatting of the output will be slightly different (notice the extra indent of the `child` end tag:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parent>
  <child>
    <value1>Foo</value1>
    <value2>Bar</value2>
    <value3>Hello World</value3>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a much cleaner way of doing things compared to my own answer. Both achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree


def remove_empty_tag(tag, original_file, new_file):
    file = open(original_file, 'r', encoding='utf8').read()
    root = etree.fromstring(file)
    for element in root.xpath(".//*[not(node())]"):
        if element.tag == tag:
            element.getparent().remove(element)
    with open(new_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))


remove_empty_tag("value3", "old.xml", "new.xml")
```

This is what I was trying to achieve, and for some reason it complains about the file/data if it has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in it. So just remove it and it's fixed. Not really a duplicate because the answer from the other thread does not specify how to only remove a specific empty tag and no help on what it is actually doing or how to write it into a new file without random '\n' everywhere...

Comment: What do you mean by "complains"? What is the actual error/warning message you're getting? You shouldn't have to remove the XML declaration to get it to work. (Your sample XML isn't well-formed though because your end tags are all wrong; those would need to be fixed first.)

Comment: The example I gave would be incorrect yes because I was trying to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve with a quick dummy data. I do not feel like using private data when asking a question of this platform. The message I kept getting with the first line in the xml was `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.` and I just removed it before processing it and put it back(not manually but with some string manipulation).