# Find positions of nodes by XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to find the position of the td element which is blank on all rows (tr). In the sample below, 3rd td element is blank on all three trs.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>101</td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>201</td>
        <td></td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>301</td>
        <td>302</td>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the sample below, 1st td element is blank on all three trs.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>103</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>202</td>
        <td>203</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td>302</td>
        <td>303</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Hi CSS, welcome to StackOverflow! Before posting a new question, you could try searching the community for answers---there's a chance your question have been asked and answered already. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688185/xpath-select-tag-with-empty-value

Comment: I did searched already. The link you provided doesn't answers my question. In the link you provided we are checking for all empty column with specific name attribute. Here I do not have any attributes. I need to find the position of the td element which is blank on all three rows.

Comment: You can apply the same concept to solve your problem. I'll post the answer.

Comment: Does the table always have exactly 3 columns?

Comment: What do you expect the XPath to return, position of column that meet the criteria? In this case, I doubt this can be done using pure XPath 1.0 ...

Comment: @Keith Hall No. I just gave a sample. It can contain any number of columns or rows.

Comment: @har07 Yes.Basically I need to remove the nth td on all rows if it matches the criteria (nth td on every row should be empty).